# Google Postman: How to get properties of an Array

Tags: javascript, json, testing, automated-tests, postman

I've got a problem by checking this json properties. I want to test, if the formName is "TestForm_WF1", but I dont know how to write the test to check the properties of this strange named array:

```
{
  "#!#": [
    {
      "_type": "wfdocument",
      "formName": "TestForm_WF1",
```

normally I got some Output like

```
[
  {
    "_type": "application",
    ...
```

which I could test with the following forEach-function:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
response.forEach( function(entry) {
   test["foo"] = entry._type === "application";
   ... 
});
```

other way round was that properties have thier own properties and could be tested like:

Output:

```
{
  "license": {
    "_type": "license",
    ...
```

Testcase:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["bar"] = jsonData.license._type === "license";
```

Comment: Your last edit is another issue, so you need to ask another question.

Comment: Regarding your second issue, there's two results because your are inserting two unique keys. To differentiate the keys, add the index: `response["#!#"].forEach(function(entry, i) => { test[i + "_foo"] = ... })`.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm new, but I will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bracket notation for characters that can't be used with a dot notation:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
response["#!#"].forEach( function(entry) {
   test["foo"] = entry._type === "application";
   ... 
});
```